# Здравствуйте. Только начал изучать django. Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне добавить поле для ввода данных "сol_vo" из модели Tag в HTML

Tags: python, django

models.py

```
    from collections import OrderedDict
    #from ipaddress import summarize_address_range
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from django.dispatch import receiver
    from django.db.models.signals import post_save
    
    from accounts.models import Brigade, Profile
    #from tasks.admin import Calculation
    from django.db.models import Sum
    
    
    class Tag(models.Model):                    
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Виды работ')
        col_vo = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Количество', null=True, blank=False, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2,)
        units = models.CharField(verbose_name='Ед.изм', null=True, blank=True, max_length=10)
        price = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Цена', null=True, blank=True, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,)
        total = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Сумма', null=True, blank=True,)
        note = models.TextField(verbose_name='Примечание', null=True, blank=True,)
        ready_to_work = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Готовность работ', default=0, choices=((0, 'Не подтверждено'), (1, 'В работе'),
         (2, 'Выполнено'), (3, 'Не возможно'), (4, 'Отменено')),)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
    
        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.total = self.col_vo * self.price
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    
        class Meta:
            verbose_name = ("Виды работы")
            verbose_name_plural = ("Виды работ")
    
    class Task(models.Model):                  
        COMPANY_CHOICES = [
            ('АЮ', 'Ап-Юг',),
            ('АТ', 'АТ',),
        ]
        date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата')
        tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, verbose_name='Виды работ', null=True, blank=False, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=70, verbose_name='Адрес работ', blank=False)
        description = models.TextField(verbose_name='Подробное описание задачи', blank=False,)
        company = models.CharField(max_length=8, verbose_name='Компания', choices=COMPANY_CHOICES,)
        employees = models.ForeignKey(Brigade, verbose_name='Бригада', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
    
        class Meta:
            verbose_name = ("Задача")
            verbose_name_plural = ("Задачи")
            ordering = ['-date']
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import Tag, Task ,Calculation

class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    date = forms.DateField(widget = forms.DateInput(attrs=dict(type='date')),)

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('date', 'tag', 'name', 'col_vo', 'description', 'company', 'employees',)
        widgets = { 
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'input', }),
            'description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'textarea', }),
        }
```

views.py

```
class TaskCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):

    form_class = TaskForm
    template_name = 'tasks/create_or_update_task.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('tasks_list')
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.TaskListView.as_view(), name='tasks_list'),
    path('new-task/', views.TaskCreateView.as_view(), name='create_task'),
    path('update-task/<int:pk>/', views.TaskUpdateView.as_view(), name='update_task'),
    path('delete-task/<int:pk>/', views.TaskDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete_task'),
```

]

HTML

```
<section class="section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="columns">
        <div class="column is-offset-4 is-4">
          <div class="content">
            {% if update %}
              <h1>Изменить задачу</h1>
            {% else %}
              <h1>Добавить задачу</h1>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
          <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.non_field_errors }}
            <div class="fieldWrapper">
                {{ form.date.errors }}
                <label for="{{ form.date.id_for_label }}">Дата:</label>
                {{ form.date }}
            </div>
            <div class="fieldWrapper">
                {{ form.tag.errors }}
                <label for="{{ form.tag.id_for_label }}">Виды работ:</label>
                {{ form.tag }}
            </div>
            <div class="fieldWrapper">
                {{ form.name.errors }}
                <label for="{{ form.name.id_for_label }}">Адрес работ:</label>
                <input id="address" name="name" type="text" />                
            </div>
            <div class="fieldWrapper">
                {{ form.col_vo.errors }}
                <label for="{{ form.col_vo.id_for_label }}">Кол.во:</label>
                {{ form.col_vo }}
            </div>
            <div class="fieldWrapper">
                {{ form.description.errors }}
                <label for="{{ form.description.id_for_label }}">Подробное описание:</label>
                {{ form.description }}
            </div>
            <div class="fieldWrapper">
                {{ form.company.errors }}
                <label for="{{ form.company.id_for_label }}">Компания:</label>
                {{ form.company }}
            </div>
            <div class="fieldWrapper">
                {{ form.employees.errors }}
                <label for="{{ form.employees.id_for_label }}">Исполнитель:</label>
                {{ form.employees }}
            </div>
            {% if update %}
              <button class="button is-link" style="margin-top: 20px; width: 150px; height: 45px;">Сохранить</button>
            {% else %}
              <button class="button is-link" style="margin-top: 20px; width: 150px; height: 45px;">Добавить</button>
            {% endif %}
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### views.p

Здесь был создан объект, через который позже мы будем выводить данные:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Tag

from .forms import TaskForm


def name(request):
tag = Tag.objects.all()

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = TaskForm(request.POST)
    form.save()
else:
    form = TaskForm()

return render(request, 'path/file.html', {'tag':tag})
```

### HTML

Этот кусочек кода нужно вставить в HTML файл и он выведет все данные из БД, которые вводились в поле `col_vo`:

```
{% if tag in el %}
{{ el.col_vo }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Добрый вечер. К сожалению, не получается у меня использовать ваш ответ. Возможно я не правильно применяю HTML. Вы бы не могли HTML по подробней написать?

Comment: Код нужно вписать в часть, где вам нужно отобразить значение col_vo

Comment: Я понял, моя вина. Я наверное не правильно задал вопрос в теме. Мне нужно создать поле HTML в которое будут вносить данные.